# adlfs: create AzureBlobFileSystem with credential=None?

Tags: dask

I'm looking for the equivalent of `s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=True)` with [adlfs](https://github.com/dask/adlfs).

I'm looking through here (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/open-datasets/catalog/goes-16/) and I see `credential=None` as one option (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.containerclient?view=azure-python).